# Vuforia not showing what the webcam sees in Unity while still capturing the marker

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, virtual-reality

I am making a first-person game using Unity and Vuforia. What I'm trying to achieve is that the user can have a marker attached on an object that can be held in his hand (a bottle, a book, or toy). So when he plays the game, he can hold the object in his hand, have the object facing the webcam, and move or rotate the object to control the first person character in Unity, e.g., tilt the marker-attached bottle in physical world so the first person character moves forward in Unity's virtual world. ps. by virtual world I mean just a basic first-person character walking around in a room, not the kind of VR that involves Oculus Rift.

I just played around with Vuforia. The good thing is I can choose my own image as the marker (looks like not every marker-based Unity plug-in can do this). But with Vuforia, can I create a virtual environment that's not showing the webcam's view? I did a basic Vuforia + Unity tutorial that only shows what the webcam captures and overlays a virtual cube on the detected marker. Summary of what I need is: not showing the webcam's view but still have the webcam functioning that it can capture the marker and I can use its position/rotation. In a way you can say I am just using the marker+webcam combo as a sensor used to control my virtual world activity.

Thanks!

Comment: You should ask these questions on gamedev.stackexchange.com instead

Answer (score 0):

From what I get it appears you want to use your marker as a target object to control motion in AR..
You'll have to build the functionality in Unity only as to what you want it to do specifically according to your set gameplay..
For example if you want a virtual dog to follow a target object, one easy way to do it is to provide an offset between the marker and the game Object and play a walking/running animation.
So it will appear as if the object is always following the marker, whereas in reality it is playing same animation at a constant distance.
As far as importing the marker is concerned.. It is no different than what you must have done with your cube..
In your Vuforia account Dev Portal:

1. Download the Vuforia SDK and import in your Unity asset folder.
2. Go to Liscense Manager under Develop tab and add a Liscense Key.
3. Now go to the Target Manager and add your images in the Databse which you want as target. (make sure the image quality is good for it to work prperly)
4. Now download the database and import it in your Assets folder in Unity.
5. Now go to your Liscense Manager again and copy your Liscense key and Open Vuforia Configuration under Vuforia Behaviour (Script) when you click on AR Camera, you'll find a dialog box there, paste this key there.
6. Save the build and run your game in Unity and bring the marker in front of the Webcam and it should work properly.

Hope this helps.